# How do you name the process of collapse/expand in one word, or fold/unfold

Tags: synonyms

How would you call the process of expanding/collapsing in one word?

I need to name a Method (in programming) which will make a group collapse or expand based on it's current state (collapsed or expanded).

Comment: `void swapCollapsedState(){ collapsed = !collapsed };` ?

Comment: the problem is that you say swapCollapsed but you might as well say swapExpanded, probably will go for toggleCollapse

Comment: With no inherent advantage or disadvantage. Here, the `swap` is the important part of the name. Write both methods!

Comment: I think this is Too Localised, but FWIW I suggest that **expand** is the more "central" concept, so OP's function should probably be called *ToggleExpandedState*. Personally I prefer *toggle* where a single variable (or state) is being switched between two possible values. To me, *swap* is more suitable where the values of two variables are transposed.

Comment: The question is off-topic, as the [faq] says not to ask questions where the topic is, "Naming, including naming programming variables/classes."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would go for `toggle()`, or better still `toggleState()`.

Comment: toggle_tree_state() or toggle_node_state() to give context. Also, I thoroughly detest camelcase.

Comment: +1 for a more descriptive naming convention. 
As for camelcase... why? It makes paragraphs easier to read (compare my_first_variable=my_second_variable-my_third_variable;
with:
myFirstVariable=mySecondVariable-myThirdVariable; )
and most importantly it's faster to type.

Comment: I'll agree that typing is much easier than with a boatload of underscores, but legibility is poorer than if underscores are used. It's really too laterally condensed. Besides, most decent editors have code completion, if that's such an issue.